# Building a nested python Dictionary from list

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, nested

I have a string that could be different lengths, and I want to create a nested dictionary.  I have this so far, and just cant seem to figure out how to get over the variable depth issue.

```
    string = "a/b/c/b"
    x = string.split('/')
    y = {}
    for item in x:
      y[item] = dict()
      .............
```

I have tried many different ways, but just don't know how to build it dynamically.  The final result I would like to get to is:

```
{'a' :{'b' : {'c': {'d': {}}}}
```

Would love some feedback on design and ideas to get this going.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just update the loop as follows:

```
y = {}
for item in reversed(x):
    y = {item: y}
```

Answer (score 2):

One Line Reduce version of [@ozgur's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42848111/1219006)

```
>>> string = "a/b/c/d"
>>> reduce(lambda x, y: {y: x}, reversed(string.split('/')), {})
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}}}}
```

But I prefer the original answer from @ozgur

Comment: I preferred your first answer that you deleted. Relying on `reversed()` can be problematic if you end up having to deal with iterators/generators but that is outside the scope of OPs question.

Comment: @AChampion The `reversed` one seems so simple though. But that's a good point, although rare, there could be a generator or iterator that you want to step through

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
string = "a/b/c/b"
x = string.split('/')
x.reverse()
y = {}
count=0
for item in x:
    if count==0:
        tmp={item:{}}
    else:
        tmp={item: tmp}
    count+=1
print tmp
```

Output:

```
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'b': {}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple way of doing this is recursion:

```
def fn(s):
    if not s:
        return {}
    x, *y = s   # Python3, for Python2 x, y = s[0], s[1:]
    return {x:fn(y)}

>>> fn("a/b/c/b".split('/'))
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'b': {}}}}}
```

But if you want to do it iteratively then you are very close, just use a cursor to walk down the structure:

```
>>> y = {}
>>> c = y
>>> for item in "a/b/c/b".split('/'):
...     c[item] = {}
...     c = c[item]
>>> y
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'b': {}}}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> text = 'a/b/c/d'
>>> d = node = {}
>>> for c in text.split('/'):
...   node = node.setdefault(c, {})
... 
>>> d
{'a': {'b': {'c': {'d': {}}}}}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.